# What does the underscore (_) mean in Chinese?

Tags: meaning

Some examples of Google search:

风中的树_新浪博客
历史转折中的邓小平_电视剧_央视网

https://www.google.com.co/search?q=%E4%B8%AD%E7%9A%84&oq=%E4%B8%AD%E7%9A%84&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.534j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

What is the meaning?

Comment: Nothing. Sometimes (generally only in **informal** situations) we use the underscore to separate meaning groups.

Comment: Thanks @Stan, I'm curious why sometimes is used a lot in the same sentence but most of time it's not used at all.

Comment: 专名号（iciba: a line under or beside a word to show that it is a proper noun) http://www.zdic.net/appendix/f3.htm :　　  用于人名、地名、朝代名等专名下面。 附注:专名号只用在古籍或某些文史著作里面。为了跟专名号配合，这类著作里的书名号可以用浪线“﹏﹏”。

Comment: @user6065 That's underline as text decoration, not underline as a symbol/character on its own.

Comment: comment was not meant to contradict any preceding comment in any way，评论并不意味着以任何方式反驳任何前述评论,不过有些用户认为，很可能与问题（what ... means i. C.)有关，反正根据上述引文＂专名号只用在古籍或某些文史著作里面＂。

Answer (score 6):

I guess it becomes popular on Internet due to web technology favor. Most of web servers are built on Unix(or similar, like Linux) OS. Underscore is widely used as space replacement since space it's not allowed for variable name in most of the programming languages. Also, web pages usually in a hierarchical structure, and web page title usually contains the hierarchical information for SEO purpose. Thus the underscore symbol is introduced into web pages as a separator, although some programmers may choose the minus symbol instead of underscore.

As a conclusion, the underscore is nothing with Chinese, but a web stuff.

Answer (score 5):

The underscore is not used before the Internet came to China. Since your two examples are all **web page titles**, I guess that the underscore just functions as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore in Chinese is written under the word you're writing. It means that the word above the underscore is a noun. (Usually a name, or a place)

Comment: Did you see the two examples the OP gave? There are nothing above the underscore.